# Invalid transaction receipt returned by appStoreReceiptURL (NSData), in iOS 7

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I'm using following method to get the receipt data:

```
// Use this method instead of accessing transaction.transactionReceipt directly!
- (NSData *)appStoreReceiptForPaymentTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSData *receiptData = nil;

    // This is just a quick/dummy implementation!
    if (kiOS7) {
        NSURL *receiptFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
        receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptFileURL]; // Returns valid NSData object

    } else {
        receiptData = transaction.transactionReceipt; // Returns valid NSData object
    }        

    return receiptData;
}
```

I'm using following code to read the JSON receipt:

```
NSData *receipt = [self appStoreReceiptForPaymentTransaction:transaction];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *receiptDict = [receipt dictionaryFromPlistData:&error];
NSString *transactionPurchaseInfo = [receiptDict objectForKey:@"purchase-info"];
NSString *decodedPurchaseInfo = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[NSData dataFromBase64String:transactionPurchaseInfo] bytes]];
NSDictionary *purchaseInfoDict = [[decodedPurchaseInfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dictionaryFromPlistData:&error];

NSString *transactionID = [purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"transaction-id"];
NSString *purchaseDateString = [purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"purchase-date"];
NSString *signature = [receiptDict objectForKey:@"signature"];
NSString *signatureDecoded = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[NSData dataFromBase64String:signature] bytes]];

// Convert the string into a date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *purchaseDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[purchaseDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Etc/" withString:@""]];

NSLog(@"Raw receipt content: \n%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[receipt bytes]]);
NSLog(@"Purchase Info: %@", purchaseInfoDict);
NSLog(@"Transaction ID: %@", transactionID);
NSLog(@"Purchase Date: %@", purchaseDate);
NSLog(@"Signature: %@", signatureDecoded);
```

The `dictionaryFromPlistData:` method returns proper `NSDictionary` object for data returned by `transactionReceipt`, but it returns `nil` using data returned using `appStoreReceiptURL` -- and consequetly I don't get valid receipt!

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromPlistData:(NSError **)outError {
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:self
                                                                               options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                                format:nil
                                                                                 error:&error];

    if (!dictionaryParsed) {

        if (error) {
            *outError = error;
        }

        return nil;
    }

    return dictionaryParsed;
}
```

**Why isn't the above code working in iOS 7?**

Just to reiterate, `dictionaryFromPlistData:` correctly converts the `NSData` returned by `transaction.transactionReceipt`.

Answer (score 4):

iOS 7 has changed how receipt validation is done.  I went through the exact path you're down and got the same results.  What I found was that the receipt from `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]` requires a different method for decoding than the previous `transaction.transactionReceipt`.

Here is a snippet from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html):

> The outermost portion is a PKCS #7
>   container, as defined by RFC 2315, with its payload encoded using
>   ASN.1 (Abstract Syntax Notation One), as defined by ITU-T X.690. The
>   payload is composed of a set of receipt attributes. Each receipt
>   attribute contains a type, a version, and a value.

If you're looking for a quick fix, I've seen success here: https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS

Comment: Yep. I've used VerifyStoreReceiptiOS in a couple of apps and it works very well. Implementing all that stuff yourself would be a world of hurt. Note, you'll need to include OpenSSL in your project (statically linked) and also include [Apple's Root certificate](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) in your bundle. I would *strongly* recommend you watch the relevant WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/#308