# How to use AppStoreReceiptUrl to verify StoreKit transactions in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin, storekit

I noticed that `SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt` is obsolete in iOS 7.  The xamarin docs still point to the old methods of verification which should work as Apple states TransactionReceipt can be used for fall back.  I'd like to get my StoreKit code updated in the event TransactionReceipt disappears in the future as it should being Obsoleted now.  If anyone has sample C# code on StoreKit payment verification using the new iOS 7 methods please provide sample code.

Comment: Not Xamarin, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903879/transactionreceipt-for-in-app-purchase-is-deprecated-in-ios-7-how-can-i-replacem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955352/invalid-transaction-receipt-returned-by-appstorereceipturl-nsdata-in-ios-7?answertab=votes#tab-top

Also check Apple's docs on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally implemented this, not a big of a deal as first expected.  I used the code per the example at http://www.hassang.com/ and then I use a fallback on SKPaymentTransaction.TransactionReceipt which I also need as I still support iOS 6.

Comment: I see this is has been downvoted, which is unfortunate. Maybe you'd be able to add some sample code on how you verify the receipt stored at AppStoreReceiptUrl in your app?