# Receipt Validation iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation) and everything works. But Xcode show me that `transactionReceipt` is deprecated.

Now looking on google, I saw that you can change using this method:

```
[NSData dataWithContentOfURL:[[NSBundle MainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
```

But if I make this change, in this way:

```
/*    NSString *jsonObjectString = [self encodeBase64:(uint8_t *)transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes
                                         length:transaction.transactionReceipt.length]; 
*/

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
NSString *jsonObjectString = [data base64EncodedString];

// Create the POST request payload.
NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"receipt-data\" : \"%@\", \"password\" : \"%@\"}",
                     jsonObjectString, ITC_CONTENT_PROVIDER_SHARED_SECRET];

NSData *payloadData = [payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The validation always fails. Instead, if I leave `transactionReceipt` all works properly.

What is the problem?

**Note**: Tested on iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.

Comment: @iTroyd23 no on device

Comment: @Ilario is your device running iOS 7?

Comment: Is it possible that it is your base64 encoding causing it to fail? What is the JSON object that you get?

Comment: @sbarow in both cases jsonObjectString is very long and the log is something like: ewoJInNpZ25hd ... etc etc.. What could I change?

Comment: @Ilario why not try `NSString *jsonObjectString = [self encodeBase64:(uint8_t *)data.bytes length:data.length];` cause that has obviously worked before, if it fails then you can rule out the base64 issue.

Comment: @sbarow I tried it and it is the same, validation fails... so the problem is NSData *data = ...

Comment: @Ilario have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903879/transactionreceipt-for-in-app-purchase-is-deprecated-in-ios-7-how-can-i-replacem read the comments and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955352/invalid-transaction-receipt-returned-by-appstorereceipturl-nsdata-in-ios-7? answertab=votes#tab-top I think you might be running into the same problem.

Comment: And here is an open source solution for you https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS :-)

Comment: @sbarow thanks for the link, I knew them, but both answers are not able to solve the problem. I guess I'll try to implement open source project

Comment: @Ilario have a look at the open source project code, it should give you some clues as to what is going wrong. I feel just changing to `appStoreReceiptURL` isn't all that is needed and might need a different approach there after.

Comment: @sbarow perhaps it is so .. the apple documentation is not very clear sincerely.. anyway thanks

Comment: So it works with SKReceiptRefreshRequest but not with appStoreReceiptURL? The appStoreReceiptURL file definitely exists? Why are you passing ITC_CONTENT_PROVIDER_SHARED_SECRET? This is not an autorenewing subscription.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman as i wrote in question i followed a tutorial... but this tutorial was for iOS 6... have you any suggestion?

Comment: @Ilario Follow https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1- for iOS 7 receipt validation

Comment: @z22 thanks, but again return ever Invalid transaction - failed transaction